# PostgreSQL query and table structure improve performance

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, table-structure

I have a table **daily_data** to save entries, sales, hours(can be 100 types) of stores. My plan is to calculate conversion, entries/hour, sales/hour, ... of many stores(can be 1000 stores).

It can be data of 1 day, 2 days or months, years.

| id_pos | date | data_type | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-11-01 | 1 | 100 |
| 1 | 2021-11-01 | 2 | 20 |
| 1 | 2021-11-01 | 3 | 8 |
| 2 | 2021-11-02 | 1 | 50 |
| 2 | 2021-11-02 | 2 | 10 |
| 2 | 2021-11-02 | 3 | 8 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

**data_type** column explanation:

1. entries
2. sales
3. hours

***id_pos**: ID of store location

**My query:**

```
select id_pos,data_type, sum(value) as data
from daily_data 
where id_pos IN (1,2) AND date>='2021-11-01' AND date<='2021-11-30' 
group by id_pos,data_type
```

After execute above query I handle result in coding to calculate Conversion(sales/entries), Sales per hour, Entries per hour, ... (handle formula with many exception cases).

```
| id_pos | data_type        | value |
| 1      | conversion       | 20%   |
| 1      | entries per hour | 20.1  |
| 1      | sales per hour   | 5.6   |
```

**The question:**
This structure will be enough with small data, but when I have 10-20 mil of rows then the query performance will be not good!
So my plan is to make a new "total_data" table, to save data of conversion, entries per hour, sale per hour(after execute above query). by this way I can directly select the final data without handle any formula in coding.

| id_pos | date_begin | date_end | data_type | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-11-01 | 2021-11-30 | conversion | 10 |
| 1 | 2021-11-01 | 2021-11-30 | entries/hour | 20.1 |
| 1 | 2021-11-01 | 2021-11-30 | sales/hour | 5.1 |
| 2 | 2021-11-01 | 2021-11-30 | conversion | 22 |
| 2 | 2021-11-01 | 2021-11-30 | entries/hour | 6.2 |
| 2 | 2021-11-01 | 2021-11-30 | sales/hour | 6.5 |

But the problem is the the date range, its can be 2021-11-02 to 2021-11-05 or thousand of cases. How can I make a properly "data_total" table?

Comment: "the problem is the the date range, its can be 2021-11-02 to 2021-11-05 or thousand of cases" => What is the logic to generate automatically the date ranges ? We need to know the logic to be implemented.

Comment: hi @Edouard : the date range is from client or analysis expert side, they can choose any date that they want.

Comment: before storing data in the new total_data table, you need first to create a function with the expected date range as input parameters, and the result of the query as output parameter. Then the function result can be stored in the table.

Comment: Do you have an index on `(id_pos, date)`?

Comment: @Edouard : yes I did this step already, just got stuck with the final step.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : I tried with all index possible, it's slow down the query when the data so big. anyway I have to apply ML, DL for it, so I have to find a solution for "total" daily data

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include the definition of all indexes you have (or tried)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you always want the values 1 and 2 for `id_pos`, you could define a partial index to speed up your query:

```
CREATE INDEX ON daily_data ("date") WHERE id_pos IN (1, 2);
```

If the values for `id_pos` are variable, your best option is to have two indexes, one on `id_pos` and one on `"date"`.

Comment: thanks you, unfortunately I have thousand of value for id_pos. its dynamic value